# Is there a **simple** way to redirect object file creation into a specified directory with Makefile project?

Tags: makefile

The project I work on is organised in one folder with a root Makefile, and a lot of sub-project each one being a subfolder containing its own makefile.

The root Makefile invokes make into each subdirectory (`make -C` command). Object files are generated at the same level as the source files.

I would like to order the root make command to redirect object file generation(and retrieving) into a specified build_dir. Is there a simple way of doing this ? (Instead of modifiying every Makefiles in every sub-project).

Comment: Is your problem only to separate out object files from source directory ?

Comment: You could put a command into the root makefile, to *move* the object files after they are built. This is a hack, but it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of a hack, but you can do this with a combination of a compiler wrapper and [`vpath`](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/ask-mr-make/11088-the-basics-vpath-and-vpath).

Suppose we have `foo.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hi there\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and `bar.c`:

```
int bar() {
    return 1;
}
```

Putting `vpath %.o obj` inside the Makefile will tell `make` to look inside the `obj/` directory for object files. But we need to tell the compiler to write object files into the `obj/` directory. `gcc` has no such option—but we don’t have to use `gcc`, we can write our own compiler wrapper that calls `gcc` with a modified command line.

`cc-wrapper`:

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTDIR=obj

#

function push() {
  # usage: push ARRAYNAME ARG
  # adds ARG to the end of ARRAY
  eval $1[\${#$1[@]}]="\$2"
}

ARGS=()
change_dir=false

mkdir -p "${OUTDIR}"

for (( i = 1; i <= $#; i++)); do
      eval arg="\${$i}"
      if $change_dir; then
        arg="${OUTDIR}/${arg}"
        change_dir=false
      fi
      if [ -e "${OUTDIR}/${arg}" ]; then
          arg="${OUTDIR}/${arg}"
      fi
      if [ "${arg}" = "-o" ]; then
        change_dir=true
      fi
      push ARGS "${arg}"
done

echo gcc "${ARGS[@]}"
exec gcc "${ARGS[@]}"
```

It’s an ugly shell script, but all it's doing is modifying some arguments:

- if the previous argument was `-o`, add `obj/` to the start of this one
- if the current argument is a file in `obj/`, add `obj/` to the start

and then calling `gcc`.

Then the Makefile is:

```
CC=./cc-wrapper

vpath foo obj
vpath %.o obj

foo: foo.o bar.o

clean::
    rm -rf foo.o bar.o foo obj
```

Now, all your objects go in `obj/` and `make` tracks dependencies correctly.

It'll take some tuning to make this ready for production—you'll probably want to rewrite the script in a comprehensible language like Python—but this should help you get started.

Comment: I've more or less followed your solution: two gloval variable VPATH and CXX. CXX points to my own scipts which looks for '-o' g++'s option and add the right path. Anyway thnx to everyone, now it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

No solution that would prevent you from modifying every Makefile.

`Makefile`s and `make` are no magic. The `Makefile` contains the command line that is used to compile each source file. Therefore, to be able to generate all the object files in a specified directory, you'd have to modify every `Makefile` to change this command line adding options telling *where* to place the object files.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like a fallback target akin to

```
%:
    make -C $(dir $@) $(notdir $@)
```

so that you can

```
make somedir/sometarget
```

?

Comment: No sorry that's not what I meant. In other words, I tried to ask the following question: is it possible to **override** the "target" directory where object files are created? Don't know whether I am clearer ?

Comment: Whether you'd need to modify your Makefile depends on what's in there. If your compile command has something like `-o $targetdir/....`, then you can pass the value for `$targetdir`, otherwise, you'd probably need to either work on your makefiles or avoid using them for the purpose.